# Reflection and implicit operator in c#

Tags: c#, reflection, struct

I'm trying to do some reflection in c# on a struct that implement implicit operator.

I've got a class

```
public class MyClass {

ObjectWrap<String> myObject;

}
```

And my object wrap is defined here :

```
 public struct ObjectWrap<T>
  {
    public T _value;

    public ObjectWrap(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator ObjectWrap<T>(T value)
    {
        return new ObjectWrap<T>(value);
    }
}
```

With this code, I can assign like that

```
ObjectToWrap<string> d = "MyValue";
```

But doing it by reflection not works ?

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
PropertyInfo p = c.GetType().GetProperty("myObject");
p.SetValue(c, "MyValue", null);
```

Gives me exception : "Cannot convert from String to ObjectToWrap`1[System.String]"

How can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: To use that operator, you would have to resolve `op_Implicit` manually and use `.Invoke`, or perhaps cheat via `dynamic` if the scenario fits

Comment: Not really duplicated, in my case, there's generics :(

Comment: That doesn't change anything...

Comment: It was a response to "marked as duplicate", not to you Marc :-)